# npm install --save-dev gulp-install

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I'm pretty new to Node and Gulp. I worked with it before, and want to set up a new project but I am having some trouble.

I am trying to install gulp in my project root. But get this in my command prompt after running `npm install --save-dev gulp-install` along with a node_modules folder with 136! folders/modules inside.

```
E:\XAMPP\htdocs\test>npm install --save-dev gulp
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\package.json'
E:\XAMPP\htdocs\test
`-- gulp@3.9.1
  +-- archy@1.0.0
  +-- chalk@1.1.3
  | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1
  | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
  | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
  | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
  | `-- supports-color@2.0.0
  +-- deprecated@0.0.1
  +-- gulp-util@3.0.7
  | +-- array-differ@1.0.0
  | +-- array-uniq@1.0.2
  | +-- beeper@1.1.0
  | +-- dateformat@1.0.12
  | | +-- get-stdin@4.0.1
  | | `-- meow@3.7.0
  | |   +-- camelcase-keys@2.1.0
  | |   | `-- camelcase@2.1.1
  | |   +-- decamelize@1.2.0
  | |   +-- loud-rejection@1.3.0
  | |   | +-- array-find-index@1.0.1
  | |   | `-- signal-exit@2.1.2
  | |   +-- map-obj@1.0.1
  | |   +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.5
  | |   | +-- hosted-git-info@2.1.4
  | |   | +-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0
  | |   | | `-- builtin-modules@1.1.1
  | |   | `-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1
  | |   |   +-- spdx-correct@1.0.2
  | |   |   | `-- spdx-license-ids@1.2.1
  | |   |   `-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.2
  | |   |     `-- spdx-exceptions@1.0.4
  | |   +-- object-assign@4.0.1
  | |   +-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1
  | |   | +-- find-up@1.1.2
  | |   | | +-- path-exists@2.1.0
  | |   | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1
  | |   | |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4
  | |   | `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
  | |   |   +-- load-json-file@1.1.0
  | |   |   | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.3
  | |   |   | +-- parse-json@2.2.0
  | |   |   | | `-- error-ex@1.3.0
  | |   |   | |   `-- is-arrayish@0.2.1
  | |   |   | +-- pify@2.3.0
  | |   |   | `-- strip-bom@2.0.0
  | |   |   `-- path-type@1.1.0
  | |   +-- redent@1.0.0
  | |   | +-- indent-string@2.1.0
  | |   | | `-- repeating@2.0.1
  | |   | |   `-- is-finite@1.0.1
  | |   | |     `-- number-is-nan@1.0.0
  | |   | `-- strip-indent@1.0.1
  | |   `-- trim-newlines@1.0.0
  | +-- fancy-log@1.2.0
  | | `-- time-stamp@1.0.1
  | +-- gulplog@1.0.0
  | | `-- glogg@1.0.0
  | +-- has-gulplog@0.1.0
  | | `-- sparkles@1.0.0
  | +-- lodash._reescape@3.0.0
  | +-- lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0
  | +-- lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0
  | +-- lodash.template@3.6.2
  | | +-- lodash._basecopy@3.0.1
  | | +-- lodash._basetostring@3.0.1
  | | +-- lodash._basevalues@3.0.0
  | | +-- lodash._isiterateecall@3.0.9
  | | +-- lodash.escape@3.2.0
  | | | `-- lodash._root@3.0.1
  | | +-- lodash.keys@3.1.2
  | | | +-- lodash._getnative@3.9.1
  | | | +-- lodash.isarguments@3.0.8
  | | | `-- lodash.isarray@3.0.4
  | | +-- lodash.restparam@3.6.1
  | | `-- lodash.templatesettings@3.1.1
  | +-- multipipe@0.1.2
  | | `-- duplexer2@0.0.2
  | |   `-- readable-stream@1.1.14
  | +-- object-assign@3.0.0
  | +-- replace-ext@0.0.1
  | +-- through2@2.0.1
  | | +-- readable-stream@2.0.6
  | | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2
  | | | +-- inherits@2.0.1
  | | | +-- isarray@1.0.0
  | | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.6
  | | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31
  | | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2
  | | `-- xtend@4.0.1
  | `-- vinyl@0.5.3
  |   +-- clone@1.0.2
  |   `-- clone-stats@0.0.1
  +-- interpret@1.0.0
  +-- liftoff@2.2.1
  | +-- extend@2.0.1
  | +-- findup-sync@0.3.0
  | | `-- glob@5.0.15
  | |   +-- inflight@1.0.4
  | |   +-- minimatch@3.0.0
  | |   `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0
  | +-- flagged-respawn@0.3.2
  | +-- rechoir@0.6.2
  | `-- resolve@1.1.7
  +-- minimist@1.2.0
  +-- orchestrator@0.3.7
  | +-- end-of-stream@0.1.5
  | | `-- once@1.3.3
  | |   `-- wrappy@1.0.1
  | +-- sequencify@0.0.7
  | `-- stream-consume@0.1.0
  +-- pretty-hrtime@1.0.2
  +-- semver@4.3.6
  +-- tildify@1.2.0
  | `-- os-homedir@1.0.1
  +-- v8flags@2.0.11
  | `-- user-home@1.1.1
  `-- vinyl-fs@0.3.14
    +-- defaults@1.0.3
    +-- glob-stream@3.1.18
    | +-- glob@4.5.3
    | +-- glob2base@0.0.12
    | | `-- find-index@0.1.1
    | +-- minimatch@2.0.10
    | | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.3
    | |   +-- balanced-match@0.3.0
    | |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
    | +-- ordered-read-streams@0.1.0
    | +-- through2@0.6.5
    | | `-- readable-stream@1.0.34
    | `-- unique-stream@1.0.0
    +-- glob-watcher@0.0.6
    | `-- gaze@0.5.2
    |   `-- globule@0.1.0
    |     +-- glob@3.1.21
    |     | +-- graceful-fs@1.2.3
    |     | `-- inherits@1.0.2
    |     +-- lodash@1.0.2
    |     `-- minimatch@0.2.14
    |       +-- lru-cache@2.7.3
    |       `-- sigmund@1.0.1
    +-- graceful-fs@3.0.8
    +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
    | `-- minimist@0.0.8
    +-- strip-bom@1.0.0
    | +-- first-chunk-stream@1.0.0
    | `-- is-utf8@0.2.1
    +-- through2@0.6.5
    | `-- readable-stream@1.0.34
    |   `-- isarray@0.0.1
    `-- vinyl@0.4.6
      `-- clone@0.2.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\package.json'
npm WARN test No description
npm WARN test No repository field.
npm WARN test No README data
npm WARN test No license field.
```

I reinstalled Node.js to v4.4.3, and gobally installed gulp before executing the command. I try to follow along with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNlEK8qrb0M).

My project folder is located on drive E, node is installed on this drive too. (My boot drive and Program Files are located on drive C). I have Windows 10.

Hope somebody can help! I'm looking forward to work with gulp, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It's a warning, don't worry about it (it's good to have a package.json though). About the number of folders created, those are gulp's dependencies, it's normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a `--save-dev` npm will look for your `package.json` and add your packages to the devDependencies.

It is likely that you have not generated one. You can do so by

```
npm init
```

and follow the prompts, or

```
npm init -Y
```

to accept all default values.

Comment: And how about the `deprecated graceful-fs`, `lodash` and `graceful-fs` warnings?

Comment: those warnings mean that the modules are no longer maintained, so they'll no further versions or bug fixes to it. It is up to you to use them at your own risk.

Comment: So does this mean that I should ingnore this worning ......ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-20:~/react-mobapp$ sudo npm install --save-dev gulp-react;
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ gulp-react@3.1.0
updated 1 package in 13.43s